# font-face not working when deployed to host

Tags: html, css

I'm using an otf font-face for my html website, it works fine on computer desktop, but when I deployed it to host, the font-face stops working. I add the image to show difference.

I included all the files, the files on my desktop and host are identical.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPYFD.png]

```
 <style>
        @font-face
        {
        font-family: proxima-nova-regular;
        src:    url("proxima-nova-regular.otf") format("opentype");
        }
        @font-face
        {
        font-family: proxima-nova-regular-italic;
        src:    url("proxima-nova-regular-italic.otf") format("opentype");
        }
        @font-face
        {
        font-family: proxima-nova-bold-regular;
        src:    url("proxima-nova-bold-regular.otf") format("opentype");
        }
        @font-face
        {
        font-family: proxima-nova-bold-regular-italic;
        src:    url("proxima-nova-bold-regular-italic.otf") format("opentype");
        }
        html, body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .topbanner
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 35px;
            background:rgb(35,35,35);
        }
        .topbannerinside
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            float: right;
            font-family: proxima-nova-regular;
        }
        .topbannerinside:hover
        {
            color: rgb(0, 232, 255);
        }
        .container
        {
            width: 1150px;
            height: 400px;
            background: rgb(250,250,250);
            border-radius: 50px;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        .header
        {
            width: 350px;
            height: 40px;
            font-family: proxima-nova-regular;
            font-size: 42px;
            top: 30px;
            left: 60px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .subheader
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 90px;
            font-family: proxima-nova-regular;
            font-size: 14px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 440px;
            top: 30px;
        }
        .selectregion
        {
            width: 460px;
            height: 280px;
            background-size: cover;
            background-image: url(samplescreen.png);
            border: dashed;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 55px;
            top: 110px;
        }
        .play
        {
            width: 112px;
            height: 112px;
            background: url(play.png);
            position: absolute;
            left: 540px;
            top: 200px;
        }
        .play:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .play:active
        {
            top: 202px;
        }
        .stop
        {
            width: 112px;
            height: 112px;
            background: url(stop.png);
            position: absolute;
            left: 666px;
            top: 200px;
        }
        .stop:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .stop:active
        {
            top: 202px;
        }
        .conversion
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 220px;
            background: rgb(246,246,246);
            border: dashed;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 800px;
            top: 130px;
        }
        .adsense
        {
            width: 733px;
            height: 96px;
            background-image: url(http://www.lostsaloon.com/wp-content/uploads/adsense-image-leaderboard.jpg);
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .recentlyadded
        {
            width: 1150px;
            height: 190px;
            background: rgb(250,250,250);
            border-radius: 50px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .recentlyaddedtext
        {
            width: 250px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            color: rgb(120,0,255);
            margin-left: 90px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: proxima-nova-regular;
        }
        .recentlyaddedscreenshot
        {
            width: 190px;
            height: 110px;
            background: lightgrey;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }


.imgareaselect-border1 {
    background: url(border-anim-v.gif) repeat-y left top;
}

.imgareaselect-border2 {
    background: url(border-anim-h.gif) repeat-x left top;
}

.imgareaselect-border3 {
    background: url(border-anim-v.gif) repeat-y right top;
}

.imgareaselect-border4 {
    background: url(border-anim-h.gif) repeat-x left bottom;
}

.imgareaselect-border1, .imgareaselect-border2,
.imgareaselect-border3, .imgareaselect-border4 {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-handle {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-outer {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-selection {
}

    </style>
```

Comment: Is the paths to the font files still the same? From the URL the font files should be in the same folder as the file that the css is in.

Comment: @J2D8T yes. I didn't change anything.

Comment: just for testing...change the paths to absolute, not relative..c if it works!

Comment: @Mayank what do you mean?

Comment: @user3114062 : change => `src:    url("proxima-nova-regular.otf")` to `src:    url("http://www.mysite.com/css/fonts/proxima-nova-regular.otf")` <= this kind of link, at times,absolute paths changes problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple possibilities:

1. What is the host server type (e.g. Apache, IIS, etc.)? Possibly, whatever is serving the OTF file is not serving it with the correct MIME type, which means it will not get processed as a font.
2. I usually put quotes around my 'font-family: "blah blah";'

Comment: thanks. http://www.screenconverter.com/proxima-nova-regular.otf .. delivers no result although the file is there